# Ubuntu 20.04 keyboard Shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys

how can i get copy and paste to work in ubuntu 20.04 desktop to work?  CTRL + C and CRTL + V does nothing at file manager and browsers. Mouse working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a default Ubuntu install, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> copies text from almost everywhere, including browsers. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> pastes text in any application that supports the clipboard.

Also in the file manager, information about the selected files is copied to the clipboard. When pasting in the file manager, that information causes the files to be pasted in the current folder. Switch to the text editor and paste there to see what the file manager puts on the clipboard.

That is for a default install. If that does not work for you, then there must be a specific cause such as some configuration you performed or a hardware issue.

Comment: this is after fresh install. all i did was just run the updates. it doesn't work in text editors as well . how do i fix this...?

Comment: No idea. May be a hardware issue. This really is not normal. Try a different external keyboard.

Comment: problem solved  when i used diffrent keyboard... thanks....appreciate it

Comment: If this answer helped, then please consider "accepting" it (i.e. click the checkmark next to the question).